# Update 'dragging view' while dragging?

Tags: android

I have to change image view when it moves above specific view.

```
{

    ClipData data = new ClipData(dragBtn.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(dragBtn);
    dragBtn.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, dragBtn, 0);

}
```

`OnDragListner`, I have tried to access `dragBtn` instance but all efforts are in vain. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to change the dragged *shadow*, or the "original" view still on the layout? The former is not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes I want to modify the shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Looking at the Android source code for the View class, the `DragShadowBuilder.onDrawShadow()` method is called only once, as part of `startDrag()`, to draw itself on a Surface which is then managed by the system.